# Importing ROS Messages in Python

Tags: ros, python, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS as middleware to connect my model (in Python) and my view (in JS), so I want to keep my Python code as separate as possible from ROS-related code. My directory structure looks like:

```
.
|____CMakeLists.txt
|____cops_and_robots
| |______init__.py
| |____Cop.py
| |____Map.py
| |____MapObj.py
| |____Robot.py
| |____test
| | |____unit
| | | |______init__.py
| | | |____moveTest.py
|____msg
| |____battery.msg
| |____cmd.msg
|____package.xml
|____README.txt
|____scripts
| |____status_talker.py
| |____websocket_interface.py
|____setup.py
```

I'm trying to import `battery.msg` from my `status_talker.py` script, but Python doesn't work too well with relative imports.

I have two questions:

1. Do I need to add an `__init__.py` to my `msg` folder to be able to import `battery.msg`? I don't entirely know pythonic standards, but it seems odd that I'd need to designate `msg` as a module.
2. Is this an acceptable way to structure my package? I'm trying to be standards-compliant, but I don't know if I am!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/180069/importing-ros-messages-in-python/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the problem was with calling `setup.py` myself. The [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html) explains issues with calling `setup.py` manually screws things up.

Instead, just uncomment `catkin_python_setup()` in `CMakeLists.txt` and follow the instructions in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile).

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.msg files are not importable by python. Python modules will be generated when you build your package (with catkin or rosbuild), and placed in your package's `src/PKG_NAME/msg` directory. They will be added to your pythonpath (either automatically with catkin, or with the `load_manifest(PKG_NAME)` command with rosbuild)

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-06-30**:
Hmm - it doesn't look like I'm getting cops_and_robots.msg added as a submodule when I examine it using pkgutil even though I think I've configured my CMakeLists and my package.xml properly (see http://goo.gl/2lKTjk ). rosmsg show cops_and_robots/battery works, though.